# UILineBreakMode Vs NSLineBreakMode

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, ios6, sizewithfont

I see some UIStringDrawing methods have been updated to use NSLineBreakMode instead of UILineBreakMode in iOS 6.0:

E.g.

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
```

How can I check for this to ensure my iOS 5 users and below continue to use UILineBreakMode?

Comment: See this same question, [NSLineBreakMode enum and backwards compatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19652424/642706).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No checking is necessary. These are just enums and they map to the same values

You can see there is no real difference here:

[UILineBreakMode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#) vs [NSLineBreakMode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSLineBreakMode)

```
  enum {
   NSLineBreakByWordWrapping = 0,
   NSLineBreakByCharWrapping,
   NSLineBreakByClipping,
   NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead,
   NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail,
   NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle
};
typedef NSUInteger NSLineBreakMode



typedef enum {
   UILineBreakModeWordWrap = 0,
   UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap,
   UILineBreakModeClip,
   UILineBreakModeHeadTruncation,
   UILineBreakModeTailTruncation,
   UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation,
} UILineBreakMode;
```

Comment: they are equal but this offers no solution to the prob here

Comment: Hmm? There is no real problem.

Comment: @Daij-Djan So the solution is to change your code to use `NSLineBreakMode` to avoid compiler warnings in the latest Xcode. When compiled, the code will run compatibly on the older iOS devices.

Answer (score 1):

UILineBrakeMode is deprecated in ios6
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UILineBreakMode