# NSLineBreakMode enum and backwards compatibility

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uilabel, line-breaks

I need my app to support iOS 5+. Since prior iOS 6 the enum [`lineBreakMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/lineBreakMode) for line break mode in [`UILabel`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/) is of type [`UILineBreakMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UILineBreakMode), and it is of type [`NSLineBreakMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSLineBreakMode) for iOS 6+, what should be the best (or more correct) way to check the iOS version currently running to determine the type to be used? Is it correct to directly do something like `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]`, or is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: See this same question, [UILineBreakMode Vs NSLineBreakMode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12714956/642706).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to check the iOS version at runtime, the enum values are the same, the compiled code will not be changed when moving from `UILineBreakMode` to `NSLineBreakMode`

```
enum {

NSLineBreakByWordWrapping = 0,
   NSLineBreakByCharWrapping,
   NSLineBreakByClipping,
   NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead,
   NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail,
   NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle
};
typedef NSUInteger NSLineBreakMode


typedef enum {
   UILineBreakModeWordWrap = 0,
   UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap,
   UILineBreakModeClip,
   UILineBreakModeHeadTruncation,
   UILineBreakModeTailTruncation,
   UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation,
} UILineBreakMode;
```

Comment: I get compiler warnings if I only set `UILineBreakMode`, won't it complain if I just set `NSLineBreakMode` and I run on iOS 5?

Comment: No, it won't complain if you use the enum `NSLineBreakMode` and it will work correctly on iOS5. `UILineBreakMode` has been deprecated but you may use safely `NSLineBreakMode`. I guess they decided to remove this duplicate enum and deprecate the UI one.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to check for the OS version you can use this code:

```
+ (NSInteger)OSVersion
{
    static NSUInteger _deviceSystemMajorVersion = -1;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _deviceSystemMajorVersion = [[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."][0] intValue];
    });
    return _deviceSystemMajorVersion;
}
```

Comment: Another more straightforward way to check for the system version is: `if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        //put your code here
    }`